# Creating a block by block matrix indicating number of lines/columns of each block

Tags: matrices

An image is better than words sometimes, so I would like to create a matrix like this:

[image]

My main problem is to put the number of lines-column using the bracket as shown here. Indeed my current code is the following and doesn't have those brackets:

```
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
I & A_1 & A_2 & B & C_1 & C_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & D_1 & I & E_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & D_2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
```

How to have the same rendering as in the image ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it with `blkarray`, `bigdelim` and a pinch of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut, bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{1ex}
\begin{blockarray}{rccc|ccc}
\begin{block}{rcccccc}
 & \overbrace{}^{r}& \overbrace{}^{\mathclap{n-k-r-s}} & \overbrace{}^{r + s} &
 \overbrace{}^{r} & \overbrace{}^{\mathclap{n-k-r-s}} & \overbrace{ }^{r + s} \\[-1.5ex]
\end{block}
\begin{block}{r[ccc|ccc]}
\ldelim\{{1}{2mm}[$\scriptstyle r $] & I & A_1 & A_2 & B & C_1 & C_2 \bigstrut\\[0.5ex]
\ldelim\{{1}{2mm}[$\scriptstyle\mathllap{n-k-r -}s$] & 0 & 0 & 0 & D_1 & I & E_2\\[0.5ex]
\ldelim\{{1}{2mm}[$\scriptstyle s$] & 0 & 0 & 0 & D_2 & 0 & 0 \bigstrut[b] \\
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]